# simple macro at spreadsheet not running native function

Tags: google-apps-script

In the `script.google.com/macros/d/1RrM3WOd....` page I have

```
function WD_HYPERLINK(x) {
  return HYPERLINK("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"+x,x)
}
```

so, when I  use it in its originator (a `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HwIH...`  spreadsheet page), calling `=WD_HYPERLINK('Q131303')` in a cell, it runs but not recognize the native function `HYPERLINK()`.

> line 2, HYPERLINK not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HYPERLINK** is a formula. you can't use it as you did. You have to set the formula to a cell.

```
var myFunction = '=HYPERLINK("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/&'+x+'", '+x+')';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   .getSheetByName("SheetName")
   .getRange("A1")//cell
   .setFormula(myFunction);
```

**But** [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions#using) : Custom functions `(WD_HYPERLINK(x))` return values, but they cannot set values outside the cells they are in.

**It doesn't work like this..**

```
function WD_HYPERLINK(x) 
{
  var myFunction= '=HYPERLINK("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/&'+x+'", '+x+')';
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();   
  cell.setFormula(myFunction);
}
```

In your case you can simply use (it will display full link though),

```
 function WD_HYPERLINK(x) 
 {
    return  "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/&"+x;
 }
```